# How to retrieve all records that exists in a specific relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a class of computer and each of it can be assembled. I need to retrieve those records of Computer class that has Assembler. I've tried to use criteria but could not retrieve them.

```
@Entity
public class Computer{
  ....
  @OneToMany
  private Set <Assembler> assemblers;
  ....
}

@Entity    
public class Assembler{
  ...
  @OneToOne
  private User user;

  @OneToMany
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  private Set<Tools> tools;
  ....
}

@Entity
public class Tools{
   ....
   @OneToOne
   private Electronic electronic;

   @OneToOne
   private Manual manual;

}
```

Code

```
 Criteria cre = session.createCriteria(Computer.class, "computer")
                       .createAlias("computer.assembler", "assem")
 cre.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.eq("assem.id",null)));
 List computer = (List<Computer>) cre.list();
 System.out.println(computer.size()): << returns zero but should return 1
```

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: Do you have to use criteria or you can use HQL?

Comment: @Ean does not matter, I just need to retrieve the correct records.

Comment: Is this what you need? `select distinct(computer) from Assembler`

Comment: assembler does not have any computer member, but computer has assembler member

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
 cre.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.eq("assem.id",null)));
```

Try:

```
 cre.add(Restrictions.isNotEmpty("assemblers"));
```

(remove the alias)

Answer (score 1):

```
from Computer computer inner join computer.assemblers as assem
```

Comment: it returns "computer.assemblers table does not exist", as it is "one to many" relationship I changed that to computer_assemblers but the result showed all reocords of computers

Comment: Hmm, could it be because of alias? What if you say `from Computer c inner join c.assemblers as assem`?

Comment: same problem when I change it to computer_asseblers it shows all records of computer and addes assembler column to all of them showing the id of one of the assemblers that is only associated to one of them

Comment: I tested exactly same and works just fine for me (does narrow down with inner join). So not sure why you are getting all parents.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Computer> list = session.createCriteria(Computer.class).setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.property("property.field1")).list();
```

Comment: does not it return all the computer records?

Comment: it is wrong you can not set projections.property in method of criteria also not using "as"

Comment: http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/example-on-hibernate-criteria-with-multiple-projections/

I'm not sure what you mean by the last comment, but good luck.